# Why do I need to sleep?

Tags: mmo-incremental

I can see why I need to gather food and wood, as well as eat, but why do I need to sleep? Does Zen do anything? Do bad things happen if I stop sleeping?

Comment: Don't you expend Zen to gather wood or food?

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought it took energy to gather food, but it requires zen. Add it as an answer!

Comment: can you paste the link to this game ? i cant seem to find it

Comment: @Elgert http://mmoincremental.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleep gives you Zen, which is what is used for collecting food. You need food to get energy, and energy is what you need in order to get wood for more upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

The implicit question here, I assume, is "can my zen reach zero without consequences?" The answer is "yes," if you don't consider the chance of a failed action due to poor planning to be a consequence.

Zen is just another resource (or "stat" as the code refers to it), not HP or something similar that can't run out. Having low zen has no effect on your efficiency and is treated just like food or wood that can be spent to receive other things.